# Can't read connection string from web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, web-config

I have the following in my `web.config` located at the root of my project:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <clear />  
    <add name="Default" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Server=tcp:whoops;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=3000;" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ConnectionString" value="test"/>
  </appSettings>
  ....
```

I read from `Startup.cs` (this is an asp.net core web app):

```
 string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Default"].ConnectionString;
```

However when I break on this, `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` and `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` are empty (well, the first has some default connection string that is not the one in `web.config`).

What's going on here?

Comment: asp.net-core does not use configuration manager nor read from web.config. those settings are stored in appsettings.json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to migrate the config to the new file appsettings.json
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/configuration?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Answer (score 3):

Not saying this is how you *should* do it, but you can do the following...

In ASP.Net Core 2.2, you should be able to add an XML configuration to IConfigurationBuilder using

```
configBuilder.AddXmlFile("app.config");
```

Contents is pretty much the same as above...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings configSource="connectionStrings.config" />
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Test" value="TestValue" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

You should then be able to access AppSettings/ConnectionStrings using...

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings

ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys
{string[1]}
    [0]: "Test"
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Test")
"TestValue"
```